# PHP-SQL: If ?page=1 in the URL is pre-set to the homepage, how are other '?pages' set?

Tags: php, sql, get

In the thedigicraft online tutorial for developing dynamic websites, the main example traverses between pages using the browser's response to this: ?page=#. It also works on my project; when I type `http://localhost/trying/?page=1`, it goes to the project's homepage. I'd like to know how one sets what page opens with `?page=2` and other numbers. In the tutorial's project example, he then uses the _get array to define defaults, but there's no explanation for how his ?page=2 opens up that project's about page, for example. What am i missing - would appreciate any light on this.

Comment: ok - i get it, in fact `?page=2` only worked after he passed a query based on `$_GET(page)`. thanks. my brain is a little fried from marathon sessions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `page` is a `GET` parameter. The page being loaded is whatever is defined in the server's configuration. In apache it is `documentroot`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot

So your page probably is `index.php`. In that page you could have something simple like:

```
if($_GET['page'] == 2) { 
      echo '<title>Other page</title>'; 
} else { 
      echo '<title>Home page</title>';
}
```

Which would display `Home Page` as the title for every page unless `http://localhost/trying/?page=2` is loaded.

You can extrapolate this concept to SQL queries for content loading etc..